# React Native Stack navigator - onPress to another page

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am new to react native and am trying to get my button to navigate to the SignUpEmail page. I origianlly had the onPress in the GetStartedButton code but recently tried putting it into the actual welcome.js page considering it can see the navigator from the stack being rendered. I cant seem to figure out how to get my button to direct me to the page I want! Any insight is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

I get the error that it cannot find navigation in line 23 of GetStartedButton.js and it points to the set of parenthesis immediately after onPress

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import WelcomePage from './src/pages/Welcome';
import SignUpEmailPage from './src/pages/SignUpEmail'

import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default class App extends Component {
 
  createHomeStack = () =>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component= {Welcome}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUpEmail" component= {SignUpEmail}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.welcomeScreen}>
       <WelcomePage/>
      </View>


    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcomeScreen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black'  
  },
  signupemailScreen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#272933' 

  }
}
);
```

GetStartedButton.js <-- Just the button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Animated  } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

export default class GetStartedButton extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  
      this.fadeAnimation = new Animated.Value(0)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.fadeAnimation, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 5000,
          useNativeDriver: true,      
        }).start()
      }

    render(){
        return(
        <Animated.View style={[styles.container, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpEmail')} >
            <LinearGradient   
                 
            colors={['#DB004C','#FC008E']}
            style={styles.linearGradient}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
            >
              
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Get Started
                </Text>     
               
             </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
    )
    
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        
    },
    linearGradient: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: 340,
        padding: 20,
    },

    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    }
});
```

Welcome.js <-- the page where the getstarted button is located

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import GetStartedButton from '../components/GetStartedButton';



export default class WelcomePage extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.fadeAnimation = new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.fadeAnimation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      useNativeDriver: true,      
    }).start()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        <View style={styles.containerClub}>
        <Animated.Text style={[styles.title, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation}]}>Word</Animated.Text>
        </View>
        
      <View style={styles.containerCaption}>   
        <Animated.Text style={[styles.caption, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation}]}> words words words  </Animated.Text> 
      </View>
          
      <View style={styles.containerBottom}>   

        
      
          <GetStartedButton/>
         
        

        
      </View>
    </View>

    );
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerMain: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },

containerClub: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 288
  },

  containerCaption: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 250

  },
  /* To style the button and positioning*/
  containerBottom: {
    
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 100
  },
  /* To style "Word"*/
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: "bold",

  },
  /* To style "Words words words"*/
  caption:
  {
   color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  line: {
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor:'black',
     margin:10,
  }
}
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Final Output:**

[image]

Make the following changes :

**App.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import WelcomePage from './WelCome';
import SignUpEmailPage from './Signup';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomePage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUpEmail" component={SignUpEmailPage} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

**Welcome.js:**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import GetStartedButton from './GetStartedButton';

export default class WelcomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fadeAnimation = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.fadeAnimation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        <View style={styles.containerClub}>
          <Animated.Text
            style={[styles.title, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation }]}>
            Word
          </Animated.Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.containerCaption}>
          <Animated.Text
            style={[styles.caption, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation }]}>
            words words words
          </Animated.Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.containerBottom}>
          <GetStartedButton
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpEmail')}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**GetStartedButton.js:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

export default class GetStartedButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fadeAnimation = new Animated.Value(0);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.fadeAnimation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.container, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation }]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.onPress();
          }}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['#DB004C', '#FC008E']}
            style={styles.linearGradient}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Get Started</Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the working [Expo Snack Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/authentic-truffle).

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate the help, how would I go about editing the white bar at the top? Ive googled around for 10 minutes but cant seem to find any good information. Could you point me in the direction of where I could find how to do so? Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do with that white status bar?

Comment: here is nice article about how you can customize it: https://aboutreact.com/custom-header-using-navigation-options-in-react-native/

Comment: That article is gold. You are the man! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, and nice job with app styling. Looks sleek.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the stack but not rendered it in App.js. Instead you render Welcome page directly add the created stack to return method:

```
export default class App extends Component {
 
  createHomeStack = () =>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component= {Welcome}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUpEmail" component= {SignUpEmail}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.welcomeScreen}>
       {this.createHomeStack()}
      </View>


    )
  }
}
```